# How to assign specific row to specific user in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

I need to allow the users of Google Documents write only in the rows, that are assigned to them. Is there any way to prevent writing to lines that do not belong to the user?

Comment: You mean table rows? There's no way to protect specific parts of documents, as far as I'm aware. Would you consider using Sheets instead?

Comment: @Iamblichus can you please duplicate your comment as an answer so i can mark it as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

Unlike Sheets, there's no way to protect specific parts of Google Docs.

#### Feature request:

If you are interested in this, I'd suggest you to request this feature by clicking `Help > Help Docs improve` on the Docs editor.